# Node JS Async.parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I'm learning node and would like to optimize the code I did. I tried using Async.parallel to perform the operations and when finished return a json.
I am new to js node and I'm trying to do with async.parallel but I returned [Function] in other code that I'm trying to understand it

```
getTabletIntRout: function(req, res) {
    var reqMAC = req.param('id_tablet');

    Tablet.findOne(reqMAC).populate('rout_tablet').exec(function(err, tablet) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!tablet) return next();

      var arrRoutes = tablet.rout_tablet;
      if (arrRoutes.length > 0) {
        var routesNotRemoved = [];
        arrRoutes.forEach(function(route) {
          if (route.removed == 'no') {
            Rout.findOne(route.id)
              .populate('rout_assigned') // Pin
              .populate('in_rout') // Tablet
              .populate('rout_description_assigned') 
              .exec(function(err, rout2) {
                var arrRout = rout2.rout_assigned;
                var routsNotRemoved = [];
                if (arrRout.length > 0) {
                  arrRout.forEach(function(ruta) {
                    if (ruta.removed == 'no') {
                      routsNotRemoved.push(ruta);
                    }
                  });
                }

                var arrTablets = rout2.in_rout;
                var tabletsNotRemoved = [];

                if (arrTablets.length > 0) {
                  arrTablets.forEach(function(tab) {
                    if (tab.removed == 'no') {
                      tabletsNotRemoved.push(tab);
                    }
                  });
                }

                var arrDesc = rout2.rout_description_assigned;
                var descripNotRemoved = [];

                if (arrDesc.length > 0) {
                  arrDesc.forEach(function(desc) {
                    if (desc.removed == 'no') {
                      descripNotRemoved.push(desc);
                    }
                  });
                }

                rout2.rout_assigned = routsNotRemoved;
                rout2.in_rout = tabletsNotRemoved;
                rout2.rout_description_assigned = descripNotRemoved;
                routesNotRemoved.push(rout2);
              });
            }
          });

          setTimeout(function() {
            if (routesNotRemoved.length > 0) {
              res.json({ info: routesNotRemoved });
            } else {
              return res.json({"error": "-1", "message": "Todas las rutas asociadas a esa tablet están eliminadas"});
            }
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          return res.json({"error": "-2", "message": "No existen rutas asociadas en esa tablet"});
        }


      }););});}},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to provide some thoughts, hopefully some will make sense in your domain.

1. **Extract a function to make people understand what you're doing in that big function**

So instead of

```
Tablet.findOne(reqMAC).populate('rout_tablet').exec(function(err, tablet) { // ...
```

You would have

```
Tablet.findOne(reqMAC).populate('rout_tablet').exec(meaningfulFunctionName);
```

2. **Don't repeat yourself**

So your code becomes shorter and whenever the reader of your code finds a function name he / she already knows what is happening inside that

```
if (arrRout.length > 0) {
  arrRout.forEach(function(ruta) {
    if (ruta.removed == 'no') {
      routsNotRemoved.push(ruta);
    }
  });
}
```

No need to check for empty `arrRout` as the argument function to `arrRout.forEach` will simply not run in the case of `length` being zero.

What you wrote is just a filter function, so why not using `filter`? Like so

```
arrRout.filter(function(ruta) {
  return ruta.removed == 'no';
});
```

You can also reuse this, if you extract the anonymous function, for `arrTablets` and `arrDesc`.

On the argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

3. **Don't use a huge `if else`**

Either check for the inverse or return a default or something that makes sense in your domain, but don't have that big chunk of logic, it makes it hard to reason about your code.

4. **Extract more function so that it's easier to use `async`**

You might want to have something like this

```
async.waterfall([
  function(next) {
    // here you can put 
    // Tablet.findOne(reqMAC).populate('rout_tablet').exec
    // invoke next with err, tablet
  },
  function(tablet, next) {
    async.each(arrRoutes, function(arrRoute, nextEach) {
      // write your code logic here
    });
  }
], function() {
  // decide what to invoke res.json with
});
```

Remember to extract functions after you're done putting the logic inside the async steps, I didn't do it so it is more clear where to put what.

I hope this makes sense, feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Next time you post a question please make sure to properly indent it, don't just paste it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you are my hero. Now I have understood new things :D

Comment: You are welcome, if this answers your question don't forget to give me some rep by +1 and accepting :D

Comment: Now, allways return me, an empty array... I think that is because I dont call the callback with the array and call first that check the code inside second function 'function(tablet, next)'. How can i solved it?

Comment: Don't post an answer as a new question or to show progress, you are better off with a fresh new question, or with an edit :) 
About your question, there are multiple ways to do so, the easiest is to declare variables outside the `async.waterfall`, see it working, and then start the refactor, if you don't like it.